# How can i get the events emitted from a transaction ID in rust client?

Tags: anchor-client, transaction

I am trying to fetch the events emitted in a transaction so that i can parse the data and use it on the client. But wondering on how i can fetch it on the anchor client in rust since i couldnt find any function which did that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply retrieve the transaction with an RPC client and read through the logs to extract events.

```
use solana_rpc_client::rpc_client::RpcClient;

let rpc_client = RpcClient::new(...); // your network here
let signature = // your signature
let encoded_transaction = rpc_client.get_transaction(
    &signature,
    UiTransactionEncoding::Json,
)?;
let logs = encoded_transaction.transaction.meta.unwrap().log_messages;
```

More information at https://docs.rs/solana-rpc-client/latest/solana_rpc_client/rpc_client/struct.RpcClient.html#method.get_transaction